# To verify one of two strings for multiple number of elements on the page

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I am working on selenium automation using page object modal. I have a scenario where I have multiple elements on the page. I have identified the element location on the page:

```
By jobStatus = By.xpath("//span[@ng-bind='::getJobStatus(job.firewallStatus)']");
```

There are 13 elements with text 'ACCEPTED' or 'REJECTED'.

I have a filter that only display elements with text 'ACCEPTED' and I want to automate this scenario to verify that all those fields ONLY contains 'Accepted'

Comment: How are `By jobStatus = By.xpath("//span[@ng-bind='::getJobStatus(job.firewallStatus)']");` and `text 'ACCEPTED' or 'REJECTED'` related to each other?

Comment: @DebanjanB jobStatus return 13 elements that display text 'ACCEPTED' or 'REJECTED'

Answer (score 1):

To verify if all those 13 fields contains only the elements with text as **Accepted** or not you can club up the clause with your filter criteria as follows :

```
if (driver.findElements(By.xpath("//span[@ng-bind='::getJobStatus(job.firewallStatus)'] and contains(.,'ACCEPTED')")).size() == 13)
    System.out.println("All the 13 fields are 'Accepted'");
else
    System.out.println("All the 13 fields are NOT 'Accepted'");
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the xpath is going to return multiple elements, you can say:

```
var jobStatus = By.xpath("//span[@ng-bind='::getJobStatus(job.firewallStatus)']");

foreach(WebElement status in jobStatus)
{
    string statusText = status.getText();
    //here assert if text equals to APPROVED
}
```

And that should do the trick